# 'beforeunload' Chrome Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this simple piece of code -

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    alert("Good Bye")
});
```

Works great with Firefox, IE8 but not in Chrome. Is it a known problem or is there any alternative for that ?

Actually what I am trying to do is to log details whenever user tries to close the browser.

```
function LogTime()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "log.php",
      data: "",
      cache: false,
      success: function(response)
      {
      }
    );
}

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    LogTime();
});
```

This works well in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Comment: Dialogs are blocked for `onbeforeunload` in Chrome because Chrome chose to do so.

Comment: The Google Chromium team highly recommends that you **not** use JavaScript dialogs (`alert()`, `confirm()`, and `prompt()`) since they state they harm users, so thats probably why they block it without first a user interaction:  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy They recommend to use the Notification API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: So why Gmail shows a warning dialog before quit site and HOW was it accomplished?

Comment: This is highly annoying, as I allow the user to upload files, and if they navigate away before the upload is complete, I wish to ask them if they would like to abort the upload. Google is becoming like Microsoft in that they make lots of assumptions on what they think your code will do, but can't cater for all scenarios and so force you to write hacks.

Answer (score 18):

Return a string instead:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return "Good bye";
});​
```

Comment: I have edited my question, Please check if a solution is possible

Comment: @Sachyn I know of no solution. I just tried a few attempts to send asynchronous data, but the traffic is blocked by Chrome.

Comment: Right. Even I cant get this working in Chrome. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: Because Chrome and Firefox requires some user action in order to notice the beforeunload.

Comment: Hello @Sampson, 10 years fast-forward, would you have a solution to recommend regarding the asynchronous data send?

Comment: @jumping_monkey Sounds like you might want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API. Though be warned, some security-oriented browsers may block that API by default.

Answer (score 7):

Try this for all Browsers:-

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";     
  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;           
  return confirmationMessage;       

});
```

Comment: The message does not appear, but this seems to at least spawn the confirmation window, thanks

Comment: This doesn't work in 2021.

Answer (score 6):

Try below:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  return "Good Bye";
});
```

Comment: i dont understand. where is the "Good Bye" used.

Comment: As at 09/10/17 , Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (32-bit), it doesn't seem to be :/

Answer (score 6):

I had to include it in a  jQuery(document).ready to get it working in chrome

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready( 
    function () { 
      jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload',  
        function (e) {  

          [code here]

        } 
      );

    } 
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Finally found the solution. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function LogTime(){

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "log.php",
  data: "",
  cache: false,
  success: function(response){

  }
});
```

}

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
     LogTime();
     return "You're leaving?";
 });
```

It seems that as long as you return a string for this event at the end of function body, you can run code before that string.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send some analytical data just before unloading the document, choose [navigator.sendBeacon()](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/#sec-sendBeacon-method) method instead of XMLHttpRequest.

sendBeacon() method is designed to perform non-blocking sending of a small amount of data.

But check [canIuse report](https://caniuse.com/#search=beacon) first, since the method is not supported globally yet.