# NextJs How to trigger a function when a user leaves a page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've found [this comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2476#issuecomment-563190607) to match what I'm looking for. It seems to work, for me, perfectly with "console.log". I want to know when a user has left the page:

```js
const getChatRoomId = () => {}

useEffect(() => {
  const chatRoomId = getChatRoomId()

  if (chatRoomId) {
    console.log('----HAS ENTERED /messages/* ------', chatRoomId)
  }

  // I believe this is not important?
  const routeChangeStart = url => {}

  // This is very important
  const beforeunload = e => {
    if (chatRoomId) {
      console.log(`---- IS LEAVING /messages/${chatRoomId} ------`)
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeunload);
  Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', routeChangeStart);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeunload);
    Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', routeChangeStart);
  };
}, [someStateChangeVariable])
```

The above works great but using a function inside `beforeunload` does not work. I've made some searches and one states to "[return a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680544/beforeunload-chrome-issue)":

```js
[..]

// This is very important
  const beforeunload = e => {
    if (chatRoomId) {
      alert(`---- IS LEAVING /messages/${chatRoomId} ------`)
    }
    
    return 'GoodBye!'
  }

[..]
```

> Blocked alert('---- IS LEAVING /messages/1 ------') during beforeunload.

I'm using NextJs [catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) `/pages/[...messages]` where you can have a page id of "new" or "123" where "123" is the message id and "new" to create a new message. How to trigger a function when a user leaves a page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `router.events` methods: [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents).

Also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664479/detect-when-a-user-leaves-page-in-next-js) might be relevant.